# spring-data-jdbc: query entity containing 1-n relation with JOOQ

Tags: spring-boot, jooq, spring-data-jdbc

I am trying to load entities containing a reference to another entity (1-n) with the help of JOOQ (based on spring-data-jdbc).

I'm started extending the [spring-data-jdbc-jooq-example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jdbc/jooq/README.adoc).

The adjusted model with the 1-n relation:

```
@Data
public class Category {

    private @Id Long id;
    private String name, description;
    private AgeGroup ageGroup;
    private Set<SubCategory> subCategories;

    public Category() {}

    public Category(Long id, String name, String description, AgeGroup ageGroup) {
        this(id, name, description, ageGroup, new HashSet<>());
    }

    public Category(Long id, String name, String description, AgeGroup ageGroup, Set<SubCategory> subCategories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.ageGroup = ageGroup;
        this.subCategories = subCategories;
    }
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SubCategory {

    private @Id Long id;
    private String title;

}
```

I wrote two queries, one via the `@Query`-Annotation in the `CrudRepository` and one with the help of `JOOQ` in the `JooqRepository`.

```
interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long>, JooqRepository {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM category")
    List<Category> findAllWithQuery();

}
```

```
public interface JooqRepository {

    List<Category> findAllWithJooq();
}
```

```
public class JooqRepositoryImpl implements JooqRepository {

    private final DSLContext dslContext;

    public JooqRepositoryImpl(DSLContext dslContext) {
        this.dslContext = dslContext;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Category> findAllWithJooq() {
        return dslContext.select()
                .from(CATEGORY)
                .fetchInto(Category.class);
    }
}
```

(for me both methods should return the same result-set b/c they execute the same query?!)

But my unit-test fails:

```
@Test
public void exerciseRepositoryForSimpleEntity() {
  // create some categories
  SubCategory sub0 = new SubCategory(null, "sub0");
  SubCategory sub1 = new SubCategory(null, "sub1");
  Category cars = new Category(null, "Cars", "Anything that has approximately 4 wheels", AgeGroup._3to8, Sets.newLinkedHashSet(sub0, sub1));

  // save category
  repository.saveAll(asList(cars));

  // execute
  List<Category> actual = repository.findAllWithJooq();
  List<Category> compare = repository.findAllWithQuery();
  Output.list(actual, "JOOQ");
  Output.list(compare, "Query");

  // verify
  assertThat(actual).as("same size of categories").hasSize(compare.size());
  assertThat(actual.get(0).getSubCategories()).as("same size of sub-categories").hasSize(compare.get(0).getSubCategories().size());
}
```

with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [same size of sub-categories] 
Expecting actual not to be null
```

As you can see in the following output the sub-categories queried by `JOOQ` will not be loaded:

```
2019-11-26 16:28:00.749  INFO 18882 --- [           main] example.springdata.jdbc.jooq.Output      : ==== JOOQ ====
Category(id=1,
    name=Cars,
    description=Anything that has approximately 4 wheels,
    ageGroup=_3to8,
    subCategories=null)
2019-11-26 16:28:00.749  INFO 18882 --- [           main] example.springdata.jdbc.jooq.Output      : ==== Query ====
Category(id=1,
    name=Cars,
    description=Anything that has approximately 4 wheels,
    ageGroup=_3to8,
    subCategories=[SubCategory(id=1,
    title=sub0),
    SubCategory(id=2,
    title=sub1)])
```

This is the used database-shema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category (
  id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  description VARCHAR(2000),
  age_group VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sub_category (
    id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(100),
    category INTEGER
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the JOOQ variant, JOOQ does the conversion from `ResultSet` to object instances. Since JOOQ doesn't know about the interpretation of aggregates as it is done by Spring Data JDBC it only hydrates the `Category` itself, not the contained `Set` of `SubCategory`.

Spring Data JDBC on the other hand interprets the structure of the `Category` and based on that executes another statement to load the subcategories.